# Creating my first rails blog app from rubyonrails.org

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

On running rails server inside the blog folder (also I have successfully installed the required bundles in the blog folder) I get this error:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:423:in `block in error_message': undefined method `>' for < 2.0, >= 1.3.0:Gem::Requirement (NoMethodError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:410:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:410:in `inject'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:410:in `error_message'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:391:in `version_conflict'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:129:in `block in resolve'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `catch'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:127:in `resolve'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:151:in `resolve'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:90:in `specs'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:135:in `specs_for'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:124:in `requested_specs'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/environment.rb:23:in `requested_specs'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:11:in `setup'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/ayush/Rails/blog/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Heres the Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'


# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. 
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease.
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

boot.rb

```
# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)

require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])
```

Please point out where I am going wrong.Also i am new to this forum so if I did something wrong in posting the question pls do tell me.
Btw I am using ubuntu terminal. 
I am using

Rails 4.0.0

ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [x86_64-linux]

Mysql2 for my database

Over the days banging my head I figured that its due to ruby and rails not being compatible...Can anyone tell me how to fix that ?

Comment: Show, please, your gemfile.

Comment: What ruby version are you using?

Comment: do not mention your rails version in gemfile. it's a bad practice.

Comment: @HasanIqbalAnik I doubt that very much. Any sources to back that up?

Comment: Can you show me the contents of /home/ayush/Rails/blog/config/boot.rb?

Comment: @Arjan , actually it is my respected senior who told me this and I am doing my projects without it without any problem.

Comment: @HasanIqbalAnik I don't want to get into an extended discussion here about this. But it is not bad practice according to the Rails developers, consindering that they put it in the Gemfile by default. Also the word of your "respected senior" isn't a credible source.

Comment: Can anyone tell me atleast what is the source of problem?

Comment: try inside your app directory `gem install bundler` `bundle update` Also if it won't help setup the latest ruby version (2.0) P.S. 1.9.3p0 is very slow.

Comment: @itsnikolay I am still getting the same error :(

Comment: @user2563862 try delete Gemfile.lock and run `$ bundle install` again. I think there's dependensies problem.

Comment: @Arjan ok, I shall consult with him again. thnx anyway.

Comment: @itsnikolay still the same error

Comment: HELP me out pls,i am stuck at my first app :(

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved it.

There was some error with compatibility of rails and ruby and i solved that by completely removing the ruby1.8 version as it was somehow selecting it manually.